# Colaboratory - access to private repository from github

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

in colaboratory i can excecute bash command with "!" simbol like
`bash
!git clone repository-name`

for cloning github repository.

It's work perfectly when repository is public, but doesn't work when **repository is private**, because it request user name / password without a input.
How could i solve this issue?

thank you a lot!

Comment: What happens when you use HTTP clone with a username and password? e.g., `!git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass username and password from url itself:-

```
!git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
```

Comment: can password be provide at run time?

Answer (score 4):

**Since 2021, Github has migrated from using username and password to using a Personal Access Token.**

In order to clone your repository using a personal access token

1. Navigate to https://github.com/settings/tokens
2. Click on "Generate New Token", and provide the appropriate permissions an define the expiry date. Do assign a note for it for you to remember it's use, and click on generate token.
3. Copy and keep the token saved with you in a secure space.
   4  To clone the repo use->git clone `https://<PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN>@github.com/username/repo.git`

Answer (score 0):

For info, doing "!git something" will retrieve your last command starting with git, and append "something" to it.
Anyway, your error to me seems to imply that you had a column in your former git command or in "repository-name", and the column was followed by a "a"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think git supports inputing passwords in one line when cloning now according to: https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ ; but I found this: https://medium.com/@purba0101/how-to-clone-private-github-repo-in-google-colab-using-ssh-77384cfef18f